# php substr without memory consumpsion

Tags: php, memory, substr

I need insert short string into long string. My problem is, that substr of string cost memory... is any way how slipt long string into two without eating new memory.

```
 $str = "xxx...yyy"; // 10 MB

 $insert_str = "insert here";

 // now split long string and insert short string

 echo substr($str, 0, 5000000); // eats next 5 MB
 echo $insert_str;
 echo substr($str, 5000000); // eats next 5 MB
```

my problem is that script ends with fatal error: out of memory
but don't won't and cann't add extra memory for this

I can't use substr_replace ... because nothing is replaced... is inserted text

I can't use any file operation, because text is generated dynamically (isn't in file)

Comment: Please explain the real problem, not your "solution".

Comment: If you define a 10 MB string in PHP, you're doing something wrong anyways.

Comment: 10 MB String? damn, my whole website (only counting php, js and css files) aren't even 10 MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `substr-replace`, but I'm unsure of it's memory usage.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

**EDIT**

Perl handles string operations much more efficiently. You would need to execute your script once your output your file to a location on your server.

```
$perl = new Perl();
$perl->require("inserter.pl");
```

Another good solution if you are working in PHP is to use `preg_replace`.

Comment: What is the aim of your answer then? Do you assume OP cannot read documentation?

Comment: @zerkms Noted. I know using perl would be a very fast way to applying string manipulation. It would require an exec command though. I'll make an edit to make my answer worthwhile.

Comment: "handles string operations much more efficiently" --- it makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens someone on the php site has posted an example of a similar scenario.

```
$token_symbols = " \t\n";
$str = file_get_contents('10MB.txt'); // 9.75410079956 MB
tokenize($str, $token_symbols); // 9.75426483154 MB
unset($str);
strtok('', ''); // 0.0543975830078 MB


function tokenize($str, $token_symbols, $token_reset = true) {
    $word = strtok($str, $token_symbols);
    while (false !== $word) {
        // do something here...
        $word = strtok($token_symbols);
    }

    if($token_reset)
        strtok('', '');
}
```

The following is an example function which will free up memory afterwards.

-- [strtok() PHP manual](http://php.net/strtok#Hcom103051)

Comment: Why instead of giving an answer for presumably silly question not wait for the real explanation of what should be solved?

Comment: @zerkms I try not to presume any question is silly just because I'm unaware of why he needs the answer.

Answer (score 0):

may be do like this:

```
$str = "xxx...yyy"; // 10 MB

$insert_str = "insert here";

// now split long string and insert short string

for($i=0;$i<5000000;$i++){
    echo $str[$i];
}
echo $insert_str;
$len = strlen($str);
for($i=5000000;$i<len;$i++){
    echo $str[$i];
}
```

Comment: extremly slow... if can speak about MB means milions of cycles